# Sandbox Solution failing to load

Tags: 2010, event-receivers, sandbox-solution, solution-deployment

Okay I think I'm missing something when I'm trying to build an Event Receiver. I'm new to this so please excuse my ignorance. But when I try to deploy an Event Receiver I always get a `Could not load file or assembly 'TestDeployBlankER'` error in ULS. I've created a blank ER to test this.

**CODE**

```
namespace TestDeployBlankER.EventReceiver1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List Item Events
    /// </summary>
    public class EventReceiver1 : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
       /// <summary>
       /// An item is being deleted.
       /// </summary>
       public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           base.ItemDeleting(properties);
       }


    }
}
```

**ULS**

```
Event manager error: Could not load file or assembly 'TestDeployBlankER, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842fa6bb627ec365' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Event manager error: Could not load file or assembly 'TestDeployBlankER, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=842fa6bb627ec365' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I always get these when two errors one right after the other when I try to debug my solution. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

I also see these errors when I just try and do a deploy.

```
Solution Deployment : Looking for 'ReceiverAssembly' attribute in manifest root node for solution 'TestDeployBlankER.wsp'.

Solution Deployment : Looking for 'ReceiverClass' attribute in manifest root node for solution 'TestDeployBlankER.wsp'.

Solution Deployment : Missing one or more of the following attributes from the root node in solution TestDeployBlankER.wsp: assembly '', type ''.
```

I found this [article](http://www.arunagarwal.net/2011/09/windows-sharepoint-services-solution.html) talking about the feature Activate, Deactivation, Installation, Uninstalling, and Upgrading events. Am I supposed to implement soemthing for these events even on a simple ER?

Comment: You shouldn't need to implement anything for those. I did see a weird reference somewhere the if the base solution was an empty sharepoint project and not an event receiver project, it didn't work. What base project did you start from?

Comment: I used the event receiver template.

Comment: There is a server in the farm that is `not configured.` I think I read somewhere that could cause an issue. Could that be a culprit>

Comment: Looks like any solution uploaded to this farm is failing. Something must've gotten changed when we migrated data to 2013.